# How to get data from database inside DataTables upon custom filtering?

Tags: python, django, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am using DataTables for my tables in my Django project. Now, Its like the following:

- There are Organizations (a separate Organization model)
- Each organization has a project (Project model with a foreign key to organization model)
- The organization model has a ManytoMany relationship with the user model, i.e, a user can be a member of mutiple organizations simultaneously.

My DataTables look like so currently:

[image]

Now, what I want is the following:

- Add another dropdown filter in my DataTable header having options "All Organizations" and "My Organizations" that would filter the table to give the corresponding result (that is display all Organizations, a user is a member of):

[image]

- Similarly include a dropdown to display all the projects a user has access to:

[image]

All I know right now is, using python, I can get all the user's organizations using `current_user.organizations.all()` because the models.py has related_name attribute set to `'organizations'` and the organization is connected with the user model through ManytoMany field like so:

```
#models.py
class Organization(SlugModel, RandomIDModel):
    users = models.ManyToManyField('accounts.User',
                           through='OrganizationRole',
                           related_name='organizations')
```

But I don't know how to accomplish this inside the DataTables. How to proceed? Please help.

The following is the JS required to Initialize the table element as a DataTable:

```
  $('.datatable').DataTable({
    conditionalPaging: true,
    "dom": '<"table-search clearfix"f>t<"table-entries"i><"table-num"l><"table-pagination"p>',
    "language": {
      "emptyTable":     "{% trans "No data available in table" %}",
      "info":           "{% trans "Showing _START_ - _END_ of _TOTAL_" %}",
      "infoEmpty":      "{% trans "Showing 0 - 0 of 0" %}",
      "infoFiltered":   "{% trans "(filtered from _MAX_ total rows)" %}",
      "lengthMenu":     "{% trans "Show _MENU_ rows" %}",
      "search": '<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>',
      "searchPlaceholder": '{% trans "Search" %}',
      "zeroRecords":    "{% trans "No matching records found" %}",
      "paginate": {
        "next": '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"></span>',
        "previous": '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-left"></span>',
        "first":      "{% trans "First" %}",
        "last":       "{% trans "Last" %}"
      },
      "aria": {
        "sortAscending":  ": {% trans "activate to sort column ascending" %}",
        "sortDescending": ": {% trans "activate to sort column descending" %}"
      }
    },
});
```

HTML Template:

```
<!-- Organization index table -->
<table class="table table-hover datatable" data-paging-type="simple">
  <thead>
   <tr>
      <th class="col-md-10">{% trans "Organization" %}</th>
      <th class="col-md-2 hidden-xs">{% trans "Projects" %}</th>
      <th class="hidden"><!-- Hidden archived status column --></th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  {% for org in object_list %}
  <tr class="linked" onclick="window.document.location='{% url 'organization:dashboard' slug=org.slug %}';">
    <td>
      {% if org.logo %}
      <div class="org-logo">
        <span class="hidden">{{ org.name }}</span><!-- needed for sorting -->
        <img src="{{ org.logo }}" class="org-logo" alt="{{ org.name }}"/>
      </div>
      {% endif %}
      <div class="org-text">
        <h4><a href="{% url 'organization:dashboard' slug=org.slug %}">{{ org.name }}</a>
        {% if org.archived %}
          <span class="label label-danger">{% trans "Archived" %}</span>
        {% endif %}
        </h4>
        {% if org.description %}
          <p>{{ org.description }}</p>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="hidden-xs">{{ org.num_projects }}</td>
    <td class="hidden" data-filter="archived-{{ org.archived }}"></td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Please ask if any other info is needed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @davidkonrad I just edited my question with the JS that initializes the Table as a DataTable. Please ask if anythingh other than this is required. Thanks.

Comment: I could solve it, but I don't know the very first step I should take to start solving this. I am a beginner in python and JavaScript. It would be really great if you could help me get started with this problem. @davidkonrad